# Should I use C#-like property handling in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, oop

Hey SO community,
I saw here: http://www.mustap.com/phpzone_post_203_setter-and-getter an argument for using 
a type of property handling common to C#, that is:
If in C#, you can define a class like this:

```
public class Person 
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get{ return _name; }
        set{ _name = value; }
    }
}
```

then why is it wise or not to define  a similar property in php like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private var $name;    

    public function Name() 
    {
        if(func_num_args() == 0) {    return $this->name;  } 
        else {$this->name = func_get_arg(0);  }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question:  why?  What's the purpose of doing that over normal getter/setter syntax (`getName()` and `setName($name)`), or over the magic methods (that let you do `$foo->name = 'bar'; echo $foo->name;`)?

Comment: Irwin - That syntax is not what C# does, or looks like. Poor analogy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, that doesn't look clean in PHP. It's like you're trying to jam the C# way into PHP because you think it's a nice feature of C#.

I see it as: In PHP, you're making a single *function* for doing two completely different things, which doesn't make sense. Meanwhile, in C#, it is single *property*, which is designed to be a single point of access for an object to be set/retrieved.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Think long and hard before trying to port features from one language to another. PHP deals with the drudgery of getter/setters via its magic methods. You may want to take a look at those instead.

Comment: Yup, it violates the [single responsibility principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (for routines instead of classes).

Comment: i believe within my post that this method can be implemented as long as you do it properly

Answer (score 4):

You're violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by having one function be both a getter and a setter.

In c# it's just syntactic sugar, and is converted into a getter and setter, just like you should write it in php.

In fact, in c#, you can simplify it further by writing

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

And the compiler will generate a private backing field, and your getter and setter functions for you.

Comment: jQuery (an excellent piece of software) does that all the time. `x.html(foo)` sets the value, `x.html()` returns.

Comment: It is a great piece of software, though, they made a conscious decision to break SRP, and only through strict adherence to their standard can this be done.  All/most setters (methods called with an input) return a jQuery object, which allows for a chainable interface.  And the getters are parameterless...sometimes.  Things like `.attr('name')` is a getter, and `.attr('name', value)` is a setter.  This is where this starts to get confusing.  Because their functions do more than one thing depending on the parameters, the consumers of the library need to understand it.  It could be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do some additional checking of the value to be set you may want to either define `getFoo` and `setFoo` methods or even better use [property overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php). The latter will give the user the feeling of native property getting/setting. (The latter is what you do in C#. Only that there is only one method per class, not many.)

Comment: +1, i'd also mention that overloading only emulates properties, but not replaces them. There is no real support for properties in php (yet).

Answer (score 2):

it is wise, for example:

```
class Settings
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __call($key,$arguments = array())
    {
        return !count($arguments)) ? $this->data[$key] : $this->data[$key] = $arguments[0];
    }
}
```

Then doing

```
$Settings = new Settings();
$Settings->name('hello');
$Settings->foo('bar');
```

This now has created a *unlimited* amount of anonymous functions ready to use, this would usually be constructed using 2 methods, `__get` and `__set` this way you can define separation for methods and variables, example follows

```
class Settings
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($key,$val)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $val;
    }
    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to set variables like so:

```
$Settings->foo = 'bar';
```

But you can go a little further then that and create a variable registry system:

so basically you can change the above class from `Settings` to `VariableStorage` and do the following:

```
class User extends VariableStorage{}
class Profile extends VariableStorage{}
```

And use like so:

```
$Profile = new Profile('Robert','Pitt',USER_PRIV_ADMIN);
$Profile->id = 56;
$Profile->userdata = $Database->GetUserData($Profile); //Reads $Profile->id
```

So that you only have to define the methods once and as long as you build your inherit structure to a good design it can work extremely well.

Comment: ok, you have an implementation of a "property bag" (attach properties with *any* name). A useful concept. I think its worth mentioning that this could be extended to allow a *specific* set of property names, by having a subclass with a private static field that is an array of valid property names, and checking whether name is in that array -- to reject any other property name.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use a similar pattern in my PHP. I think it is clean and fairly useful.

```
private $name;
public function name($name = null)
{
    if ($name === null) return $this->name;
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

You can even do this to enforce some type safety:

```
private $name;
public function name(string $name = null)
{
    if ($name === null) return $this->name;
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

You can also enforce setting/getting of a reference instead of a copy:

```
private $name;
public function &name(string &$name = null)
{
    if ($name === null) return $this->name;
    $this->name = &$name;
}
```

This is completely valid PHP and mimics C# quite nicely.

Also, the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> The single responsibility principle is a computer programming principle that states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class.

So, this does not break the Single Responsibility Principle as this is simply a class method used to get/set a class member variable.

The only down side here is that, on the instance of your class you'd have to call functions to get/set member variables instead of true properties. You could mix this design pattern with PHP's __get and __set, but that would just be more overhead.

Comment: Minor nit:  its confusing to use `$name` as the parameter name. A more appropriate name is `$value`.