# Handling PHP properties like those in C# (getter & setter)

Tags: c#, php, properties, getter-setter

I have been doing some research over time and wanted to know if using properties in a PHP class can be done like C#, I have found these questions which game some good answers and pointers, but didn't help me really:

- [Should I use C#-like property handling in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788538/should-i-use-c-like-property-handling-in-php)
- [Get and set (private) property in PHP as in C# without using getter setter magic method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925317/get-and-set-private-property-in-php-as-in-c-sharp-without-using-getter-setter)

Although, as I said, these give good answers, I still can't make up my mind on these, for example, I want to be able to do something such as:

```
class Foo 
{
    public $bar
    {
        get { return $this->bar; }
        set { $this->bar = value; }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to!

What is the best way to do this within the constraints of PHP?

The kind of thing I have been able to come up with is this:

```
class user
{
    private static $link;
    private static $init;

    private function __construct ()
    {
        global $link;
        static::$link = $link;
    }

    public static function __INIT__ ()
    {
        return static::$init = (null === static::$init ? new self() : static::$init);
    }

    public static $username;

    public function username( $value = '' )
    {
        if ( $value == '' || empty ( $value ) || !$value )
            return static::$username;
        else
            static::$username = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `setUsername` and `getUsername` without magic methods?

Comment: @S.Pols, what do you mean?

Comment: Why you dont just create a function `setUsername($variable)` and a ` `getUsername()` instead of trying to use the function as a getters AND a setter (which is in my opinion wrong). In my opinion a function should have 1 responsibility.

Comment: @S.Pols, I agree, 1 function, 1 purpose, but for this question I am really looking for the way that I could C# like implementation can be done in PHP

Comment: `if ( $value == '' || empty ( $value ) || !$value )` - you almost certainly don't want to do that, as it will prevent several valid values from being set. use `null`, and test `is_null`. Of course, that will still make it impossible to set a value to null. An inherent flaw to combining get and set into one function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what PHP magic methods are for.  They allow you to dynamically set properties through a mediator method.  Here, let me show you an example:

```
abstract class GetterSetterExample
{
    public function __get($name)
    {
        $method = sprintf('get%s', ucfirst($name));

        if (!method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return $this->$method();
    }

    public function __set($name, $v)
    {
        $method = sprintf('set%s', ucfirst($name));

        if (!method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        $this->$method($v);
    }
}

class Cat extends GetterSetterExample
{
    protected $furColor;

    protected function getFurColor()
    {
        return $this->furColor;
    }

    protected function setFurColor($v)
    {
        $this->furColor = $v;
    }
}

$cat = new Cat();
$cat->furColor = 'black';
```

Yeah... it terrifies me as well.

This is why most people are content with using methods like the ones in `Cat`, but public.  Apparently there is discussion on adding "real" getters and setters, but there appears to be a lot of conflict between those who hate them for concerns of readability, semantics and principle...

Comment: This seems to be dramatically complex for what it needs to be... What are the advantages of using the magic methods over a custom method such as the one exampled in my question? (see the username method and property)

Comment: @SamSwift There isn't any advantage to this at all.  Once upon a time I implemented getters and setters in the same way you are, but the PHP world is learning in favour of more statically declared and type safe code, and the only way to do that is with real functions with single return types.

Comment: So instead of having a function with the return of `string|void`, it's more widely accepted to have the way implemented in your example?  I personally can see the use of this and the advantage (quicker code, just use `=` I guess), but at the same time, I really like the C# `get { ... } set { ... }` for properties...

Comment: @SamSwift No, I'm saying that while the solution above emulates the "property" style API you want, it fails for the reasons you are concerned with (its dramatically complex).  The comment made by S.Pols is the generally accepted solution.  Some people however are of the school of thought where properties shouldn't exist, and classes should never open up their properties and that they should only perform operations.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to think if it's really neccessary. It is just a shorthand to write getters and setters.

```
private String _name;

public String Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

Has exactly the same function as:

```
private $_name;

public function getName()
{
    return $_name;
}

public function setName($name)
{
    $_name = $name;
}
```

There is only a difference in the call:

```
C#  : Object.Name = "This is my Name";
PHP : Object->setName ("This is my Name");
```

If you really preffer for the C# syntax (which in my opinion is just a habit), i think Flosculus's answer is the only option. It isn't that complex if you realise what the code does. 
For information:

```
__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.
```

In this example `furColor` is inaccessible since it's a protected variable.

So what happens here `$cat->furColor = 'black`.

- furColor is inaccessible so magic method __set is calling.
- It creates a setter in `GetterSetterExample` named `setFurColor` and check if it exists.
- Yeah it does exist, because `Cat` implemented it.
- `setFurColor` is called and variable is set.

In the final also this code is doing the exact same as the general getters and setters from the example above. It's just a 'workaround' to simulate C#'s properties.
So to come back on my first question of this answer, is it neccessary? In my opinion it isn't. PHP doesn't support properties, so it has no clear meaning why you would try to simulate it.
General getters and setters are the way to go and as shown in my examples it does the exact same thing.
Magic methods are slow, and good luck if you want to do this in a type safing way. The sample code of Flosculus isn't complex, but this approuch can become (unneccessary) complex.